# Adjust overlay close speed slower + close overlay upon leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the following is the HTML, CSS, Javascript, and JQuery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getTarget(event){
    target = (typeof window.event === "undefined")?event.target:window.event.srcElement;
    return target;
}

document.onclick = function(event){
    var target = getTarget(event);
    if(target.id == ""){
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
        var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    }

}


function toggleOverlay(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    var button = document.getElementById('qualityButton');
    overlay.style.opacity = .7;
    if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        button.style.color="#000000";
    } else {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
        button.style.color="#ff0000";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function toggleOverlay(){  
$('#overlay, #specialBox').fadeToggle(500);
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

div#overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #A9A9A9;
    position: fixed;
    width: 879px;
    height: 291px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 719px; 
    height: 215px;
    top: 88px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #FFF;
}
div#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:24px;
        border:none;
        color:#000
}
    .btn:hover{ 
    color:#F00; 
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    .x {
        background-color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
        font:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        color:red;
        z-index: 4;
        position: fixed;
        top: 92px;
        left: 766px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">
  <button class="x" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">X</button>
</div>
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<!-- Start Normal Page Content -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="qualityButton" class="btn" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">HIGHEST QUALITY</button>
</div>
<!-- End Normal Page Content -->



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Two things are required that I can't seem to get my head around:

1. When the 'Quality Button' is clicked, the overlay fades in. When clicked again, it fades out. However if the overlay is open, and the 'X' button is clicked to close the overlay, or if any other place on the webpage is clicked to close the overlay, there is no fade effect, and the overlay just closes in a flash. How can I achieve the fade effect when 'X' button or indeed any place on the webpage is clicked?
2. If the overlay is open, and a user goes to another page, and returns to the page with the overlay, the overlay is still open... How can I make sure that once the overlay page has been left, and if the overlay was left open, that it is closed upon return?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

James

Comment: Can you create a working example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @kthornbloom here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/4cR2h/   Everything seems to be put in correctly but the when the button is clicked nothing happens (on jsfiddle.net).